# Why this text input doesn't work on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, angularjs

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu combined with a text input field that acts as an Angular filter. The code looks like this:

```
<form name="searchForm" role="form" data-ng-submit="goSearch()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <input type="text" ng-click="load_origins()" name="dropdown-toggle" data-ng-model=origin_search placeholder="Ciudad Origen" class="btn btn-default search-menu-button dropdown-toggle" id="origin" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" required autocomplete="off">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right search-menu-items" aria-labelledby="origin">
                        <li><a href class= "search-menu-item" data-ng-repeat="origin in origins | filter:origin_search" data-ng-click="checkDestinations(origin)">{{origin.Localidad}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The thing is that:

```
<input type="text" ng-click="load_origins()" name="dropdown-toggle" data-ng-model=origin_search placeholder="Ciudad Origen" class="btn btn-default search-menu-button dropdown-toggle" id="origin" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" required autocomplete="off">
```

is not working as intented in iOS, the keyboard appears but no text appears when the user tries to write.

For what I've been searching it can be related with a bug in iOS with that particular input type, but there was no solution that worked for my case.

Is it maybe a CSS related thing? (Maybe a Bootstrap bug: http://getbootstrap.com/browser-bugs/)

Or could it be re an Angular thing? Or maybe just an iOS problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I opted to use a [Typeahead of UI-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) mostly because it seemed a good option as it behaved the same way that the dropdown that I tried to implement, but without the troubles on iOS.

So, I didn't find out what was causing the problems, after some frustration it was a better option to change the directive.